# Use Kotlins copy function with interface

Tags: kotlin, data-class

I currently have a model similar to:

```
interface FooInterface {
    val param: String
}
data class Foo(override val param: String) : FooInterface
data class Bar(override val param: String) : FooInterface
```

Classes of the type `FooInterface` are then stored and modified in a list. For example:

```
val list: List<FooInterface> = listOf(Foo("abc"), Bar("def"))
list.forEach {
    it.copy(param = "test")
}
```

This is not possible. And while I could understand that this makes sense, because the classes `Foo` and `Bar` could have more parameters. Casting would probably work, but this doesn't scale well, when using a lot of classes implementing the interface. But I feel like there is a way to achieve this, that I'm overseeing.

Comment: Add a copy function to the interface and implement it in each class.

Comment: Yes, that's what I currently do, but that also doesn't seem very elegant.

Comment: It's the best way with the features Kotlin provides.  To do it any more simply would require a language feature for a very specific use case, which would make the language more obtuse if they added it (some way for an interface to enforce all its implementers to be data classes with certain implemented properties required in the constructor). Of course, if these classes have always the same parameters, they could be merged into a single class, but I know this is probably just a simplified example. There might be a more fundamental design decision you can change that would make it more elegant.